# In Magento 2 how do i get the order number from the invoice collection factory

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice

I manage to get the order id but not the order number

```
$invoicesCollection = $this->_invoiceCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(array('*'));
$invoices = $invoicesCollection->getItems();
foreach($invoices as $invoice){
    $orderId = $invoice->getOrderId();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try many hours to get the order number from the Invoice object but I can only get the OrderId so i added the order collection factory:

```
        $ordersCollection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(array('*'))
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $invoice->getOrderId());
        $order = $ordersCollection->getData();
        $orderNumber = $order[0]["increment_id"];
```

And it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$invoicesCollection = $this->_invoiceCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(array('*'));
$invoices = $invoicesCollection->getItems();
foreach($invoices as $invoice){
    $orderId = $invoice->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
}
```

Comment: thanks but the invoice object doesn't have getOrder() i get an error